# Why does TextReader.Read return an int, not a char?

Tags: c#, unicode, character-encoding, textreader

Consider the following code ( `.Dump()` in LinqPad simply writes to the console):

```
var s = ""; //3 byte code point. 4 byte UTF32 encoded
s.Dump();
s.Length.Dump(); // 2
TextReader sr = new StringReader("");
int i;
while((i = sr.Read()) >= 0)
{
    // notice here we are yielded two
    // 2 byte values, but as ints
    i.ToString("X").Dump(); // D852, DF62
}
```

Given the outcome above, why does `TextReader.Read()` return an `int` and not a `char`. Under what circumstances might it read a value greater than 2 bytes?

Comment: Firstly, `Read()` is _virtual_, and `StringReader` overrides it. Why does it return `int`? Not sure.. but at least the last call to `Read()` will allow it to determine EOF. Also, it casts a `char` to an `int` via the internal strings indexer (`[]`) method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TextReader.Read()` will never read greater than 2 bytes; however, it returns `-1` to mean "no more characters to read" (end of string). Therefore, its return type needs to go up to `Int32` (4 bytes) from `Char` (2 bytes) to be able to express the full `Char` range plus `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

[`TextReader.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w3csw16.aspx) probably uses `int` to allow returning `-1` when reaching the end of the text:

> The next character from the text reader, or -1 if no more characters are available. The default implementation returns -1.

And, the `Length` is `2` because `String`s are UTF-16 sequences, which require [surrogate pairs](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#surrogate_pair) to represent code points above `U+FFFF`.

```
{ 0xD852, 0xDF62 } <=> U+24B62 ()
```

You can get the UTF-32 code point from them with [`Char.ConvertToUtf32()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2ys180b.aspx):

```
Char.ConvertToUtf32("", 0).ToString("X").Dump(); // 24B62
```